# Laptop won't turn on after blank screen, possible motherboard damage

Tags: laptop, motherboard, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite C660 which while I was using it the screen appeared to go blank and the machine (I think) died however both the charger light and power light remained turned on. I pressed the power button trying to restart the laptop and nothing happened so I removed the battery and plugged it back in. When doing this both the lights went out as expected but did not come back on. I have been unable to start the computer since this happened. I mean no fans, no drive starting up, no bios, nothing and know lights indicating charging or power etc. The laptop is completely dead.

Contributing factor:
A couple of months back my laptop was overheating a lot and the fan was running crazy so I decided to clean out the dust gathered inside. This was very successful fixed the problem and I do not believe has anything to do with current problem. However, when I was opening up the laptop about 80% of the cheap plastic screw mounts broke. No idea why? I was quite careful and is a procedure I have carried out on many other laptops before without any problems. Anyway as a result of this happening the laptop case isn't held together very well and I have had to be careful using the laptop. The other day just before I got the blank screen I was holding the laptop with my right hand underneath the right of the mouse. This is the area where the hard drive is connected to the motherboard. While holding the laptop the bottom case for the laptop separated from the top half causing me to bend the area where I was holding slightly. At this point the screen went blank.

What I have done to troubleshoot:

1. I have put the hard drive and motherboard in the same bending angel
   to see does it have any effect on the board and it doesn't.
2. I have taken the laptop apart and inspected the motherboard and there is no
   visible damage
3. I have tested the charger and battery (both work fine in another laptop)
4. I have tested the hard drive and ram.

Nothing seems to work. Everything looks fine.

Could there be damage to the motherboard that isn't visible to the eye? I would ppreciate any advice or where I might look next.

Comment: Sounds like a cable is disconnected or you damaged a intergrated circuit board

Comment: I think it's the motherboard that's causing problems i recommend you to go to a nearby computer repair shop,because they have got the tools to analyze it and yes don't walk in a random store ask people around you for suggestions.

Comment: When you checked the mobo for damage, did you check the components as well? It's possible that you blew a capacitor, resistor, or a trace was somehow cut. All things that would be near-invisible over a quick glance but would cause this.

Comment: @Thebluefish any advice on how I might check if I blew a capacitor, resistor, or a trace was somehow cut?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using the laptop with another monitor.  If you have a
   keyboard/mouse/monitor plugged in when the laptop lid is closed and
   boot, see if that works.
2. Look at the LCD at a high angle to see if the backlight is gone
   (you'll see a very very dim image, but it looks blank when looking
   at it directly/normally).

Comment: No the laptop is not turning on what so ever. It'd not an issue with the screen.